# Fields are always returning empty

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to create a PHP objected oriented form validation script, but I am running into a problem. Whenever I check if my fields are empty or not, the script always returns the message saying they are, even when my fields are not empty upon submission. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
<label>Full Name</label>
<input type='text' placeholder='Full Name*' name='name'>
<label>Email</label>
<input type='email' placeholder='Email*' name='email'>
<label>Password</label>
<input type='password' placeholder='Password*' name='password'>
<input type='submit' value='Sign Up!' name='registerBtn'>
</form>";
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    class CreateUser
    {
        /*Declare variables*/
        public $errors;

        public function __construct(){
            /*Initialize array of errors*/
           $this->errors = array("empty_err"=>"");
        }

        /*Function that checks if fields are empty*/
        public function checkEmpty($valArr){
            foreach ((array)$valArr as $value=>$keys){
                if (empty($valArr[$keys])){
                    $this->errors["empty_err"] = "All fields are required.";
                }
            }
        }

    }

    $user = new CreateUser();

    if (isset($_POST["registerBtn"])){
        $user->checkEmpty($_POST["registerBtn"]);

    }
?>
```

Comment: `$_POST["registerBtn"]` is not an array, it would be a string. Do you mean to loop over the `$_POST` array? If you don't already, put `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. First change**

**Change this to:**

```
$user->checkEmpty($_POST["registerBtn"]);
```

**This:**

```
$user->checkEmpty($_POST);
```

**2. Second change**

**Change this to:**

```
foreach ((array)$valArr as $value=>$keys){
   if (empty($valArr[$keys])){
```

**This:**

```
foreach ((array)$valArr as $keys => $value){
   if (empty($valArr[$keys])){
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The solution works, but why do we have to switch $value and $keys?

Comment: because you are checking `empty`  on `$valArr[$keys]` where `$keys` should be `index` and `$value` should be value on that index

Comment: So $value is always the index value?

Comment: here in your post `foreach ((array) $valArr as $value=>$keys){ ` , `$value` is index and `$keys` is the value on that index. so either you do second replacement or change this `if (empty($valArr[$keys])){` to  `if (empty($valArr[$values])){`

Comment: @user2896120 If i am not able to make you understand just refer to http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php